# How To Insert Unique Composite ID For Hierarchical Table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have this table structured as follows :

```
PK     ParentPK     ID
1      Null         A
2      1            B
3      2            C
4      1            D
5      4            E
```

For the table above, I already have a function that can generate the following results :

```
PK     FullID
3      ABC
5      ADE
```

This function takes rows that don't have children, and recursively generate FullID for each row up to their parents.

My application expects users to enter a string of FullID, such as "BEF", "ABD", and press Save button and then its the application duty to internally parse it to a suitable hierarchy structure (that will consists of multiple rows) and insert them to the table.

The question is, how can the application guarantee the uniqueness of FullID? I need to be able to reject duplicate FullID entered by users.

I understand that I can check the FullID first using my function, then if it isn't exist, I can perform the inserts. But if these steps performed in a non-atomic operation, duplicate FullID may be entered i a heavy traffic usage.

Should I wrap this in a stored procedure? using Begin/Commit Transaction block? or is there any better way to do it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for something like this

```
BEGIN TRAN
if not exists (select a.PK from GetFullID(a.PK))
begin
    --do operation--
end
commit TRAN
```

Comment: Hi, UniqueKey in what field? FullID is not a persistent field in a table, it is generated by a function.

Comment: I don't insert the FullID into any table. The FullID field is generated on-the-fly by a function like this :

Select a.PK, dbo.GetFullID(a.PK) As FULLID From TableData a

The result of the function above IS NOT INSERTED in any table.

Now how can I guarantee the uniqueness of the FullID even though it is not inserted in any table?

Comment: dbo.GetFullID(a.PK)  is table or scalar value function ?

Comment: dbo.GetFullID() is a scalar function that takes any PK, and returns the FullID in varchar, it works by recursively concatenating IDs up to its parents.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're facing questions like this is a strong code smell that your data model is flawed. If you need unique constrained, then they should be enforced by an unique constraint. In other words, the 'BEF', 'ABD' full ID should be explicitly persisted in storage somewhere and uniqueness enforced on the full id column with an ordinary unique index.